# C# UWP why can't I add a second event handler?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am new to UWP, and c#. I have a problem with canvas object in XAML, I have added event handler, which is tapped, and I tried to add, also `RightTapped`, but the event handlers menu is empty, and I can't add anything. I was looking for answer, but I couldn't find any. How to add event to canvas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just add eventhandlers through the XAML:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="Test.MainPage">

    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas" Tapped="MainCanvas_Tapped" RightTapped="MainCanvas_RightTapped"/>
</Page>
```

Then make sure your `MainPage.cs` contains a `Canvas_Tapped` and `Canvas_RightTapped` eventhandler, like this:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainCanvas_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void MainCanvas_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

If you don't want to type in the XAML you can also assign the eventhandlers to the `Canvas` after it has been initialized. In that case you need to change the `MainPage` constructor:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MainCanvas.Tapped += MainCanvas_Tapped;
    MainCanvas.RightTapped += MainCanvas_RightTapped;
}
```